# How to enable predictive text (auto-correct) in the touch keyboard for a custom control in a Windows Desktop application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When using the on-screen keyboard in Windows 8 (and Windows 10) for typing into an Edit or RichEdit control, the keyboard displays a list of word suggestions. Is there a way to enable this behavior for a custom text editor control? (Note: I am referring to the touch keyboard, not osk.exe)
[The touch keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Obviously, Windows needs to be able to access and modify the document data in my control.
I tried enabling some of the UI Automation text interfaces to no effect.
[UI Automation Support for Textual Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

My window handles the WM_GETOBJECT message:

```
HRESULT OnGetObject(UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL &bHandled) {

            if (lParam == UiaRootObjectId) {

                return UiaReturnRawElementProvider(*this, wParam, lParam, customTextProvider.get());
            }
            return 0;


            return 0;
        }
```

it returns a pointer to my custom text provider object:

```
class CustomTextProvider : public IRawElementProviderSimple, public ITextProvider, public ITextProvider2, public IValueProvider {
```

In this class I have IsTextPatternAvailable, IsTextPattern2Available, IsValuePatternAvailable, and IsLegacyAccessiblePatternAvailable all set to true. I can verify this using the Inspect utility. I can also correctly see the contents of my control for Value.Value.

Even with this, the touch keyboard shows word predictions/corrections for the edit control, but not my control.

Comment: Does your custom control implement [`WM_GETOBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373892.aspx) and [`IAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466.aspx)?

Comment: I have WM_GETOBJECT implemented, but not IAccessible. From my understanding, UI Automation supersedes MSAA, and all MSAA functionality can be provided through the legacy interface.